# Javascript efficiency: new local variable vs global vs property

Tags: javascript, browser, processor

I'm making a pretty heavy canvas effect and need to squeeze every bit of speed out of the users system.

Here's a scenario:

```
function ImCalledEveryMouseMove(blah,blah)
{
    var imgData = myctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    var somevar1 = (some maths process);
    var somevar2 = (some maths process);
    var somevar3 = (some maths process);
    var somevar4 = (some maths process);
    var somevar5 = (some maths process);
    for(every pixel channel etc){do some stuff...
    // and so on
}
```

Each of those vars are being created afresh within the function scope.

My question is:

whats the most efficient way to do this to lower the overhead?

Perhaps:

```
var imgData,somevar1,somevar2,somevar3... an so on
function ImCalledEveryMouseMove(blah,blah)
{
    imgData = myctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    somevar1 = (some maths process);
    somevar2 = (some maths process);
```

because there's no new memory allocation ?

or perhaps:

```
var cache = {};
function ImCalledEveryMouseMove(blah,blah)
{
    cache.imgData = myctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    cache.somevar1 = (some maths process);
    cache.somevar2 = (some maths process);
```

Not sure why but I read something about this being advantageous because of dynamic memory something or other but can't remember why..

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: You can squeeze all you want out of micro optimizations and they won't make a difference. Caching the mousemove event result is what's important.

Comment: currently in this format canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
            myfunction(blah, ctx, blah, textureData, 1, specularity, e.clientX+100, e.clientY+100, 200);
        }  how do you mean?

Comment: Do you really need to get new ImageData every mouse move? This will be the heavy memory task, not your five variables.

Comment: @Bergi sadly so theres a video playing in canvas, the mouse is controlling an interactive video filter